# Text around ImageView

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I found this solution to wrap my text around an ImageView: http://gmariotti.blogspot.nl/2014/03/snippet-align-textview-around-image.html.

I figured out how to add padding to the right of the image, but I also want padding at the bottom of the image.

Comment: have you tried using `android:margin` in your ImageView?

Comment: Yes and it did not work. I also tried to add the padding to the measured height of my image, which also did not work.